# Can I set up a vhost configuration using Apache 2.2.22 like this?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have 2 web sites I am trying to set-up using Apache Vhost.  The websites are setup at IP address / foldername, but are not yet exposed to the outside, no DNS.  So when I try to Vhost them like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/marion"
   ServerName IP-address/marion

   <Directory "c:/wamp/www/marion">

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride all
          Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all

   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/redcreek"
   ServerName IP-address/redcreek

   <Directory "c:/wamp/www/redcreek">

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride all
          Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all

   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and browse to either site, like `IPaddress/redcreek`, I get the error `"The requested URL /redcreek/ was not found on this server."` It is like the IP address is not recognized once I activate the Vhost configuration file.

Is it possible to configure `httpd-vhosts.conf` this way until I have registered DNS names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPaddress/redcreek` and `IP-address/marion` [are not valid `ServerName` identities](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) because it isn't a FQDN.

If you want to be able to access `http://ip-address/marion` and `http://ip-address/redcreek` then you should make a single vhose with the document root at `c:/wamp/www/`, the servername as the IP address, and include both the `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/marion">` and `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/redcreek">` blocks.

Once you have DNS names, like say, `marion.yourdomain.com` and `redcreek.yourdomain.com`, you can use the setup you have and replace the `IP-address/marion` with `marion.yourdomain.com` and `IP-address/redcreek` with `redcreek.yourdomain.com`.